# How to use Malloc pointers in comparison to array in C

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

I created a struct called PLAYER and I want to create an list that stores the pointers to the PLAYER object.

If I want to accomplish it with

```
PLAYER **ptr = malloc(10*sizeof(PLAYER *));
```

How can I assign the pointers to each index? I tried:

```
PLAYER *a;
PLAYER *b;
ptr[0] = a;
ptr[1] = b;
```

1.This seems to work. Can I get some explanation on the memory address behind it?
I also tried:

```
ptr = a;
//increase the address and assign b
ptr += sizeof(PLAYER *);
ptr = b;
```

2.This does not work correctly I think. Can I see a correct way of assign the list without using the [] brackets?

3.If I allocate only one entry's size and assign multiple ones:

```
PLAYER **ptr = malloc(1*sizeof(PLAYER *));
ptr[0] = a;
ptr[1] = b;
```

I can get these PLAYER object by using ptr[0] ptr[1], but will this cause any problems like overwrite other memories?

4.If I use [] brackets, do I need to malloc at each index in order to use it?

```
PLAYER *ptr[10];
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  ptr[i] = malloc(sizeof(PLAYER *));
```

5.Do I need to free an array after using it? such as:

```
char ptr[10] = "abc";
//do something with ptr
free(ptr);
char *ptr2[10] = {"123", "abc"};
free(ptr2);
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: One question at a time, please. 1. May compile, but not "work". 2. `*ptr++ = a;` `*ptr++ = b;` 3. Depends on what `a`, `b` are. 4. Yes but the `sizeof` is wrong. 5. Don't `free` what you didn't `malloc`.

Comment: Always use the idiom `x = malloc( count * sizeof *x)`.  That will prevent many errors.  eg, `struct p *ptr[10]; for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) ptr[i] = malloc(1 * sizeof ptr)`

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `PLAYER **ptr = malloc(10*sizeof(PLAYER *));`

That means you have to malloc for every `ptr[i] = malloc(sizeof(PLAYER));`

Accessing the array at indexes would be `ptr[i]->somevalue`

**NOTE:** if you have pointers inside the struct you need to allocate for those as well!!

Freeing your memory would be:

```
for(int i = 0; i<10;i++){
    free(ptr[i]->anyAllocatedPointersInside);
    free(ptr[i]);
}
free(ptr);
```

**SPECIFICALLY IN THAT ORDER**

If you update the post with the full struct I can update mine to more accurately help you.

Answer (score 0):

When in doubt, think of `malloc()` allocations in these terms: it allocates *raw* memory, and it doesn't know anything about your structs!
When you think in these terms, you'll get it right.

Let's try to answer to your questions:

1. You are basically instancing within the stack a pointer, with any content into it, just as `int hello;`. That integer can contain anything, because you don't set it as in `int hello = 2;`. The same thing is happening with your pointers: `int * hello;` will be a pointer (to an integer) that can contain any address. Hence, if you dereference a pointer like that, your chances to get caught into SIGSEGV are not low.
   Then, once you have created those pointers that can be anything, you're assigning their *address* to the pointer of pointers array you've allocated. Don't do that.
2. That doesn't work correctly, because if you have an array of pointers to a given type, you can simply increment with `+= n`, the compiler will calculate the appropriate "sizeof(type_you're-pointing_to)" and will add that automatically. This is the main purpose of declaring a pointer to a given type.
3. You're effectively overwriting other memory.
4. Brackets are just pointer dereferencing: `*ptr+n` same as `ptr[n]`.
5. You need to free each line, and then the array of pointers of pointers.
   Basically every pointer you get with `malloc()`, you have to free it with `free()`. DO NOT call `free()` to any other pointers that hasn't been spit out from `malloc()`.

Let me show you some code I have just written to show you better:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h> // for memset

#define N_POINTERS 4
#define M_PLAYERS_PER_LINE 3


struct PLAYER
{
  int id;
  int score;
  int age;
};


int
main()
{
  // Allocate the array of pointers, big enough to old N pointers.
  struct PLAYER ** pointers = malloc(N_POINTERS*sizeof(struct PLAYER*));
  // Always better zeroize pointers arrays.
  memset(pointers, 0, N_POINTERS*sizeof(struct PLAYER *));
  // Allocate each line of M `PLAYER` structs.
  // Basically we allocate N chunks of memory big enough to contain M PLAYER structs one next each other.
  // What we get is something like this:
  //
  // pointer      pointers              PLAYER lines
  // of pointers   array
  //   [addrP] -> [addr0] -> [PLAYER0 PLAYER1 PLAYER2] .. M
  //              [addr1] -> [PLAYER0 PLAYER1 PLAYER2] .. M
  //               ...N
  //
  int id = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < N_POINTERS; ++i)
  {
    pointers[i] = malloc(M_PLAYERS_PER_LINE*sizeof(struct PLAYER));
    // Set the data you want to the structs.
    for (int k = 0; k < M_PLAYERS_PER_LINE; ++k)
    {
      pointers[i][k].id = id++;
      pointers[i][k].score = 123 + k;
      pointers[i][k].age = 33 + i;
    }
  }

  // Print data.
  // Here we use a single PLAYER pointer that will
  // traverse the entire PLAYER matrix.
  struct PLAYER * player;
  for (int i = 0; i < N_POINTERS; ++i)
  {
    for (int k = 0; k < M_PLAYERS_PER_LINE; ++k)
    {
      // Assign the current PLAYER to our pointer.
      player = pointers[i] + k;
      // Print PLAYER data, by reading the pointed struct.
      printf("Player: #%i  age:%i  score:%d\n", player->id, player->age, player->score);
    }
  }

  // Deallocate!
  for (int i = 0; i < N_POINTERS; ++i)
  {
    // Deallocate each line chunk.
    free(pointers[i]);
  }
  // Deallocate the array of pointers.
  free(pointers);
  return 0;
}
```

As a bonus track, if you need to allocate a matrix of `M*N PLAYER` structs, you should also look at this code, that will allocate `M*N PLAYER` structs into one unique memory block, one next each other, which is much more easier to manage, as you can see by the code itself:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define LINES 4
#define COLUMNS 3
#define GET_ARRAY_POS(lin, col) (col+(lin*COLUMNS))

struct PLAYER
{
  int id;
  int score;
  int age;
};


int
main()
{
  // Allocate a *FLAT* array of PLAYER structs, big enough to
  // contain N*M PLAYER structs, one next each other.
  struct PLAYER * array = malloc(LINES*COLUMNS*sizeof(struct PLAYER));

  // Set the data you want to the structs.
  int id = 0;
  for (int lin = 0; lin < LINES; ++lin)
  {
    for (int col = 0; col < COLUMNS; ++col)
    {
      int pos = GET_ARRAY_POS(lin, col);
      array[pos].id = id++;
      array[pos].score = 123 + col;
      array[pos].age = 33 + lin;
    }
  }

  // Print data.
  // Here we use a single PLAYER pointer that will
  // traverse the entire PLAYER matrix.
  for (int i = 0; i < (LINES*COLUMNS); ++i)
  {
    // Print PLAYER data, by reading the pointed struct.
    printf("Player: #%i  age:%i  score:%d\n", array[i].id, array[i].age, array[i].score);
  }

  // Deallocate!
  free(array);
  return 0;
}
```

Enjoy! ^_^